# Can I use AJAX xmlhttprequest with a .swf file?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-2

when the user clicks the play button on my shockwave flash movie, its runs some code. i was wondering if when they click the play button it can call a javascript function that already exists within the web page, for example `loadtext();`

is this possible, and if so please tell me how.
the software that I am using is Flash 8 with Actionscript 2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this use:

```
getURL("javascript:loadtext();");
```

Note: This will only work in AS2 and not AS3.